# Can I downgrade iOS Deployment Target when submitting a new version?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, deployment-target

My app is available on the Appstore and is currently compatible with iOS 6 or later.

I want to release a new version only compatible with iOS 7 or later because there's a lot of crashes on iOS 6 with this new version and I have to release ASAP.

Here's my question : when the iOS 6 crashes will be fixed, would it be possible to bring back the iOS 6 compatiblity (i.e. downgrade the IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET from 7.0 to 6.0) ? Does Apple allow that ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know, I've never needed to (or wanted to) do it. This should probably be a question to Apple, or you should assume that you can't and work with that constraint...

Comment: First thing to remember: ios is NOT an android, almost everyone update its device to the LATEST version of iOS. Supporting older versions than current and one back is neither professional nor modern nor innovative at all.

Answer (score 3):

Your **iOS Deployment Target** can be whatever you wish it to be. The main requirement that Apple has is that your app submission is compiled against the latest SDK at the time (currently Apple is accepting base SDK of iOS 7, but it will change to iOS 8 in the new year).
When you downgrade the deployment target back down to 6, the only thing you have to ensure is that you're not calling any iOS 7+ APIs when running on iOS 6 devices, otherwise you'll be creating a lot of crash reports.

*edited after better understanding the original question*

Comment: Sorry but it does not answer to my question : if i keep iOS 6.0 for the first update, people using this iOS version will have a lot of crashes and leave bad comments on my app. That's the reason why i want to exclude them until i fix the bugs...

Comment: In theory that should not be a problem. I cannot recall any rules about changing your deployment target multiple times. If you want to support older iOS versions that's entirely your choice.  
However it's worth while for you to investigate just how many of yours users are on iOS 6 and then evaluate if it's worth your time supporting those users.